# Code gets stuck when I try to call a pointer method

Tags: c++, oop

I may or may not be dumb, but I don't see any reason why my code should work like this instead of how it's supposed to, but any explanation is welcome, as I'm completely lost in my assignment.

The part where I run into a problem is this part:

In this part, the problem occurs in the inner for in the do while loop, `legretegek` is a `vector<Legreteg*>`, viszonyokall is a string, that I give to each simulate method.
The problem is, that it only runs for the first `i` value, after that it fails. And it returns with  -1073741819.

And last the Legreteg.cpp which contains only the simulate methods:

```
#include "Legreteg.h"

using namespace std;

const char zivatar = 'z'; // ozon : - , oxigen : 50% ozon , szendioxid : -
const char napos = 'n'; // ozon : - , oxigen : 5% ozon , szendioxid : 5% oxigen
const char mas = 'm'; // ozon : 5% oxigen , oxigen : 10% szendioxid , szendioxid : -

void Ozon::simulate(char &viszony){
    cout << "eljut az ozon simulateig"<<std::endl;
    double newvastagsag = vastagsag;
    switch (viszony){
        case mas: vastagsag *= 0.95; cout << "mas"; *alakul = Oxigen(newvastagsag*0.05, "Oxigen"); cout << "mas2"; break;
        default: break;
    }
}

void Oxigen::simulate(char &viszony){
    cout << "eljut az oxigen simulateig"<<std::endl;
    double newvastagsag = vastagsag;
    switch (viszony){
        case zivatar: vastagsag *= 0.50; cout << "zivatar"; *alakul =Ozon(newvastagsag*0.50, "Ozon"); cout << "zivatar2"; break;
        case napos: vastagsag *= 0.95; cout << "napos"; *alakul = Ozon(newvastagsag*0.05, "Ozon"); cout << "napos2"; break;
        case mas: vastagsag *= 0.90; cout << "mas"; *alakul = Szendioxid(newvastagsag*0.10, "Szendioxid"); cout << "mas2"; break;
    }
}

void Szendioxid::simulate(char &viszony){
    cout << "eljut a szendioxid simulateig"<<std::endl;
    double newvastagsag = vastagsag;
    switch (viszony){
        case napos: vastagsag *= 0.95; cout << "napos"; *alakul = Oxigen(newvastagsag*0.05, "Oxigen");cout << "napos2"; break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

The main part gets as far as generating a new `Legreteg*` object into `*alakul`, but after that, the cout I placed behind it for torubleshoot reasons, doesn't get ran anymore, and this is the point when the program returns with -1073741819.

Sorry if it's too much, but I'm completely lost on the problem, and any help is appreciated.

A test input(put this in an input.txt, and write input.txt into the program):

```
4
z 5
x 0.4
s 3
x 4
mmmmnnznnmm
```

Comment: This doesn't seem the cause, but you shouldn't do `#include "Legreteg.cpp"`. Instead of this, you shoukd *link* multiple `.cpp` files to one executable binary.

Comment: Names like `legreteg` and `alakul` make it darn hard to read and understand...

Comment: `kiir(n, legretegek);` -- Using `n` after you've read it in and used it to loop for the second set of reads, is not correct.   You know the number of items added to the vector, and that is done by calling the `vector::size()` function.  Use `size()`, not `n`.  To prove this can be incorrect:  `default: cout << "Hibas bemenet: " << legretegneve << " " << vastagsag;` -- You do not add an item to the vector.

Comment: @MikeCAT If I don't include the `Legreteg.cpp` then I get vtable errors. 
@Jeffrey Sorry for making it unreadable. Sadly my professor asked us to name them mostly in Hungarian, because we would need to show this project to him in person. I would have named them in English otherwise.
@PaulMcKenzie Thank you! It's sure more elegant, but that should be good, as the first time I output from the vector it's just the n amount of data in the vector. After that I use `legretegek.size()` in the `do..while` loop

Comment: @pacuhh It is not good that you are using `n`.  The reason is simple -- what if one of those inputs does not add an item to the vector.  Let's say that `n` is 8, but one of the items was not added, thus the vector size is actually 7, not 8.  You then call `kiir` with `n` equal to 8 when the actual number of items is 7.  Thus you now have an out-of-bounds access violation in that loop in `kiir`.  Again, do not use extraneous variables like `n` for vector sizes.  All that does is increase the risk of bugs, and in your case, that is a bug.  The vector knows its own size by using `size()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no lines that sets the member variable `alakul` to values other than `nullptr`. Then you dereferenced `alakul` (`nullptr`) in the function `simulate()` like:

```
*alakul = Oxigen(newvastagsag*0.05, "Oxigen");
```

This is wrong.

Instead of this, I guess you wanted to allocate new object and assign that to `alakul` like

```
alakul = new Oxigen(newvastagsag*0.05, "Oxigen");
```

instead of dereferencing `alakul` there.

Also you may want to define

- Copy constructors
- Assignment operators
- Destructors

to handle the pointer properly on object copying. Be careful not to violate [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what my problem was! Now it's working as intended, thank you again!